# Is it possible to trigger a pipeline after the conditional met? If any, how to do that?

Tags: python, streaming, apache-beam

**Problem**:
I have a streaming data. The streaming data is coming from a single pubsub. Then, I split the data into two groups, Group A and Group B. Group A is a group that contains the code of a single event. Group B is a group that contains the transactions. I need to aggregate transaction data but after some code exists in Group A. For example, my program will start aggregating transactions after code U exists in Group A and end the aggregation after code B exists in Group A.

**Questions**:
How does the pipeline know when to start and stop based on the code in group A?

I created one example pipeline but still don't know how to get the expected result.

Suppose I have two pcollections, one for event code, one for transactions

```py
with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_options) as p:
    event = (p | "Create1" >> beam.Create([
        {"eventCode": "A", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 0, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "C", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 1, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "U", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 2, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "D", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 3, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "E", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 4, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "F", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 5, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "G", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 6, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "B", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 7, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "T", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 8, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "H", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 9, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "I", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 10, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "J", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 11, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "M", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 12, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "B", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 14, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "Y", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 15, 0)},
        {"eventCode": "X", "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 16, 0)},
    ]))

    trx_data = (p | "Create2" >> beam.Create([
        {"trxCode": "TRX001", "price": 156, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 1, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX002", "price": 157, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 2, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX003", "price": 158, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 3, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX004", "price": 159, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 4, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX005", "price": 160, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 5, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX001", "price": 161, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 6, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX002", "price": 162, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 7, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX006", "price": 163, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 8, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX001", "price": 164, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 0, 9)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX007", "price": 165, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 10, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX008", "price": 166, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 11, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX003", "price": 167, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 12, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX005", "price": 168, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 13, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX009", "price": 169, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 14, 0)},
        {"trxCode": "TRX010", "price": 170, "dates": datetime(2022, 12, 1, 7, 15, 0)},
    ]))
    
    # I made a window to simulate the streaming process
    event_window = (event
                      | beam.Map(lambda d: beam.window.TimestampedValue(d, d["dates"].timestamp()))
                      | beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(1))
                      | beam.Map(lambda d: (d["eventCode"], d))
                      | beam.GroupByKey()
                      | beam.MapTuple(lambda e, d: d)
                      )
    trx_window = (trx_data
                   | "TrxData1" >> beam.Map(lambda d: beam.window.TimestampedValue(d, d["dates"].timestamp()))
                   | "TrxData2" >> beam.WindowInto(beam.window.FixedWindows(10*60))
                   | "TrxData3" >> beam.Map(lambda d: (d["secCode"], d))
                   | "TrxData4" >> beam.GroupByKey()
                   )

    process = (trx_window
               | beam.ParDo(TransformWithSideInput(), stock_u=beam.pvalue.List(event_window))
               | beam.Map(print)
               )
```

For `TransformWithSideInput()`, I created this:

```py
class TransformWithSideInput(beam.DoFn):
    def start_bundle(self):
        self.bucket = []

    def process(self, element, event):
        for ethe  in event:
            event_code = e.get("eventCode")
            event_code_dates = e.get("dates")
            queue = []
            if event_code == "U":
                queue = ["U"]
            elif event_code == "B":
                queue = ["B"]

            if queue == ["U"]:
                # If the code U exists then start appending the data into the bucket.
                # Logically, the transactions that need to be processed are all transactions
                # that come after the time the event code arrives.
                if element.get("dates") >= event_code_dates:
                    self.bucket.append(element)
            elif queue == ["B"]:
                yield self.bucket

    def finish_bundle(self):
        if self.bucket:
            self.flush()

    def flush(self):
        yield self.bucket
```

I made `TransformWithSideInput` by putting the event pipeline as a side input. The reason because I need this event pipeline to be checked and if the conditional is met, the DoFn function can return all the data based on the event. However, the transaction pipeline returns nothing.

In this case, when `event_code == "U"` then start the transaction pipeline until the `event_code == "B"` exists, then stop the pipeline and return the result.

Answer (score 0):

Data in a distributed system need not necessarily come in any particular order, so you need to be careful about triggering processing when something else happens. Instead, determining when when one has seen "all the relevant data" is controlled by [watermarks](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/basics/#watermark). There are many resources on how to think about this, e.g. https://www.oreilly.com/radar/the-world-beyond-batch-streaming-101/

If your data can be called complete at some pre-determined time, [windowing](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing) a join on your two groups would likely work well. Otherwise, you may want to consider using [state and timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/). (Note in particular that `start_bundle` and `finish_bundle` may be called many times for a single stream of events, but state can persist beyond this.)